# Best practice for RESTFull Web services and file download

Tags: rest

I'm currently working on a RESTFull application that can provide the clients generated binary files. I'm wondering what would be the best practice :

- Send a GET request to the application, generate the file and write to the response, with the correct headers ?
- Send a GET request to the application, generate the file and write json data containing the file metadata and a link to a download servlet ?

Comment: I would say the first. What metadata do you have?

Comment: I only have the file name, the size and the mime-type

Comment: You can use the `content-type`, `content-length`, `content-disposition` headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My use case was that we might be creating a really large file, the creation process might take a while. Also, I do not want my file creation process to be interrupted as it will surely be costly to do so. So, a good solution seems to be async file generating with signaling.

Steps:

1. create a new file, `POST /downloads` (endpoint name an example), response `202 Accepted, Location: /downloads/123` (unique ID of the download). If we're sharing the files among users, the same POST might return the same ID (all the users are waiting for the same file to generate)
2. request the file, `GET /downloads/123`, file not yet completed, response `102 Processing` (and an optional progress and/or ETA, if available)
3. request the file, `GET /downloads/123`, file completed, response `303 See other, Location: https://cdn/full-path-to-generated.file.pdf`

It enables you to create really large files and take a really long time, reuse the file creation process for multiple users and also transfer the file generation process itself off form the app server to a worker.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first approach but it depends on what you want to return as metadata. As a matter of fact, you can leverage the `Content-Disposition` header to send back metadata like filename, ...

You can also notice that it's also possible to send back to the client a multipart content. This allows to mix file contents and form data.

Hope it helps you.